# How to pass state data to DesktopDatePicker through renderInput?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state, formik, yup

I'm trying to create a date-picker component but I can't manage to pass the data to the TextField component.

Is there any way to pass the newValue data to TextField through onChange or as a prop through renderInput?

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input, Box, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { useField } from 'formik'
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DesktopDatePicker from '@mui/lab/DesktopDatePicker';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import InputField from '../InputField';

const DateField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  // const [field, meta] = useField(props)

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date('2021-12-25T21:11:54'));

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log(value)
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="Date desktop"
        inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderInput={() => <InputField name='date' />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}

export default DateField
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `value` as prop?

Comment: I tried to pass the data this way `renderInput={(value) => <InputField name='date' {...value}/>}` but it didn't work.

I have a github repository of the project, would you like to take a look at it? Is it ok to post it here?

Answer (score 0):

```
   const [value, setValue] = React.useState(moment('2021-12-25T21:11:54',"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

or

```
renderInput={(props) => <InputField {...props} name='date' />}
```

Comment: You can use `useState(() => moment())` to initialize the value lazily so the moment object doesn't get created every time the component re-renders

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **renderInput** prop in your component as bellow:

```
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
        label="Date desktop"
        inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
```